# Why is 800x480 resolution so common?

Tags: lcd

The official Raspberry Pi LCD is 800x480, and there are many other popular displays that use that same resolution, at various sizes (ie Pimoroni Hyperpixel([Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3578))).  For example, I have a resistive touch 5" HDMI display at that same resolution.

It seems like a low resolution, and in experimenting with a Pi 3 and Ubuntu Mate, I confirmed that it was indeed to small to really do anything.  I'd expect similar problems with Windows at that or similar resolutions.

Yet, obviously people are buying them if the manufacturers keep selling them.  What am I missing?  Is there a scaling setting in Linux to make this resolution a better user experience?

Comment: Well, in those were the days my friend, there were only 12 inch monochrome text (80 characters x 24 lines?) monitors:  640 x 480 resolution was common, 720 x 350 was high class, and only IBM could do super high resolution 800 x 600. (1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_5151, 
(2) https://lowendmac.com/1989/apple-high-resolution-monochrome-monitor/,
(3) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3KEhWTnWvE.  Nowadays I am using 16 char x 2 lines, or 20 char x 4 lines LCD "monitor" and I think 16 char x 2 lines is more than enough.  I do use 800 x 600 pixel LCD for graphics or Chinese char  though.

Comment: I mean, if you want a terminal, that's what SSH is for, and there are plenty of ways to set that up.  But these are touchscreens and GUIs, so terminals are not relevant to this.

Comment: I now see what you mean.  Of course you can have a 5" touch screen with resolution like the Apple iPhone 6 (1334 x 750), but that would be very expensive, perhaps 5 to 10 times as expensive as the 800 x 480 cheapie.

Comment: You're getting warmer, but still not quite at the point I am trying to make.

Comment: OK.  Let me think about it and try again later.